# Storm UI Values

Tags: twitter, apache-storm

why the value of Emitted, transferred and Acked varies in the Storm UI under "Topology Stats" section and How they are getting calculated. Even if the Number of failure is Zero.

In my Case, Number of Emitted and transferred are same which is correct but the Acked is higher and also Number of failure is Zero(Which is correct). I am using Storm 0.9.3 version.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topology stats show all stats for spouts and bolts (the sum of all the emits, transferred, executed ...) at the four varies time interval.

In order to get the exact value according to the application. You just need to add/change the value of **topology.stats.sample.rate**: to 1.0 from 0.05 in storm.yaml.

what i understood is that, Storm samples incoming tuples for computing stats. By default, 5% of them are actually used for computation. When you change it to 1.0 it use 100% of the incoming tuples for computation.

Comment: it helps me Thanks but if transferred is zeros how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is as follow:

Topology stats show all stats for spouts and bolts (the sum of all the emits, transferred, executed ...)

Each bolt, spout has its own stats.
The key numbers to look at are: 
- Capacity: this really tells you if your bolt is running at full capacity or if it has some margin
- Executed: this seems to be the number of events actually processed.

Acknowledged means the event has been received and acknowledged, it doesn't mean it's been processed yet, so it makes sense that it is higher. 
Transferred and Emitted are still confusing to me too.
I suggest you try to tail the worker logs to see what is actually happening.
You can also use the metrics class to get more statistical values on topologies (see [this](https://www.endgame.com/blog/storm-metrics-how-to.html) simple example to get started)

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839173/metrics-access-and-custom-logs-files-are-empty-after-submitted