# Metrics,access and custom logs files are empty after submitted

Tags: apache-storm

After i submitted topology i found in `path/of/storm/logs` some files like `nimbus,supervisor,ui,drpc,metrics,custom and access`

but access,custom and metrics are empty , i'm asking about

- how can i access them
- why they are empty
- what is the benfit from it

Answer (score 0):

`access`, `custom`, and `metrics` are log files for different Storm features. For example: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Metrics.html

If you do not know those features and do not use them, you can simply ignore those files.

Comment: Thanks but what is the benefits from it  ?

Comment: Can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779755/storm-yaml-setting

Comment: What do you mean by benefits? What would you expect to have?

Comment: I mean in what conditions can I use those files ?